# CSS DIV Positioning and Border Issue

Tags: css, html, alignment, css-position, stylesheet

I got a Problem with CSS ! :)
I want to style a box to look like this one here: 
http://dribbble.com/shots/1151646-Home-AgenceMe/attachments/148910 (Chart + 3 boxes right).

Right now i tried:

```
.wktcontent {
   float: left;
   width: 80%;
}
.wktinfo {
   float: right;
   width: 20%; 
}
.wkttitle {
   height:34px;
   padding:5px;
   border-bottom:1px solid #000000;
   margin-bottom:20px;
}

.wktinfocontent {
  font-weight:bold;
  border-top:1px dashed #000000;
}
```

and in html:

```
<div class="wktcontent">
  <center><h2>Title</h2></center>
  <p><h3>Content</h3></p>
</div>
<div class="wktinfo">
  <div class="wktinfocontent"><p><h4>27/7/2013</h4></p></div>
  <div class="wktinfocontent"><p><h4>27/7/2013</h4></p></div>
  <div class="wktinfocontent"><p><h4>27/7/2013</h4></p></div>
  <div class="wktinfocontent"><p><h4>27/7/2013</h4></p></div>
</div>
```

I think everything aligns fine. But as soon as I add a border to the boxes by defining

```
border: 1px solid lightblue;
```

the title is placed over the infos on the right.

My second part of the Question is: How can I align the numbers on the right (as in the example on dribble) to the text next to it?

thank you so much!!

Comment: solved it by myself. I needed to put the whole thing in a wrapper which is wider than the two divs.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a border changes an elements dimensions. If you add a 1px border to an element, then remove 1px from it's width and height. Failure to do this will result in issues with layout.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your error on jsfiddle and chrome, what browser are you using?

As for the numbers, I'd suggest using a `table` in each div so you can align both halves properly.
Something along the lines of:

```
<div class="wktinfocontent">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td width="30%">
      07
      </td>
      <td width="70%">
      Hours play game today
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```